# Cannot sync OpenLDAP directory with Azure AD

Tags: openldap, entra-id

I am trying to connect and sync OpenLDAP with Microsoft Azure AD using Generic LDAP connector as described in the URL below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-connector-genericldap/

I was able to connect to OpenLDAP directory server and retrieve accounts using Full Import (stage Only) profile in Azure AD Synchronization service manager.

I tried to run the Export and Sync profile, but the statistics shows that accounts are not synced with Microsoft Azure AD. See the below screenshot.
[LDAP Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXxoA.jpg)

I checked the event logs, but couldn't find anything related to generic LDAP connector. Please let me how I can troubleshoot this issue.
￼

Comment: have you seen the troubleshooting link in that page? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-connector-genericldap/#troubleshooting What have you done to troubleshoot?

Comment: I saw that link but I did not try to enable  ETW. I will try it and let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: When I am trying to enable ETW, I couldn't find the location for forefront identity manager as mentioned. I think I missed out the exact package.

Comment: Could you please provide me the proper download links for generic LDAP connector prerequisites?

Comment: look for 'Forefront Identity Manager Connector for Generic LDAP ' in your favourite search engine ;-)

Comment: I got the Generic LDAP connector already. Actually, I need the URL for  prerequisites package (Forefront Identity Manager 2010 R2 (FIM2010R2)) of Generic LDAP connector mentioned in the above article.